# using hammer.js create a touchdrag side drawer

Tags: jquery, css, hammer.js

I just started playing around with hammer.js which is fantastic btw, but I am having trouble doing what I am looking for. I am trying to create a touchdrag drawer which will move up to a certain point if dragged open. I have written this so far...

```
$(function () {
    var mb = $('#mainbody');

    Hammer(mb).on("dragleft dragright", function (ev) {
        ev.gesture.preventDefault();
        var deltaX = ev.gesture.deltaX;

        if (deltaX > 150) {
            deltaX = 150;
        }
        $(mb).attr('style', 'transform:translate3d(' + deltaX + 'px,0,0);');

    });
})
```

...however, when my element stops to the 150px mark, as soon as I touch drag to restore it, it resets my translate to 0 and starts from there instead of where I left it. I have tried studying the hammer.js examples, but I am not that advanced to parse the code and write my own. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, please post your solution as the answer.

Comment: nope, I abandoned it because it causes all kinds of issues. you can google for snap.js